# simpMessagingTemplate convertAndSendToUser lot of waiting threads blocking other functionality

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

We are using Stomp, SpringBoot, and WebSockets in our application. The server application is doing the following: 
1) Generating messages to be pushed to the users, 
2) Accepting WebSocket connections and 
3) pushing messages to ActiveMQ stomp broker. Thread dump shows a lot of waiting threads associated with the simpMessagingTemplate convertAndSendToUser API call.

Two instances of the application are running in a cloud. This application generates messages and pushes to ActiveMQ stomp broker (running separately) using simpMessagingTemplate convertAndSendToUser API.

We use Gatling for simulating user WebSocket connections for load testing. The Gatling runs on a separate instance. The application works fine for 2000 user connections. Once we increase the users to 4000 we see that the message generation thread stops. Users are getting connected to the same servers without any problem though.

If we comment the simpMessagingTemplate convertAndSendToUser API call then everything works perfectly fine (both generate messages and new WebSocket connections). So we doubt the issue with convertAndSendToUser API.

Threaddump stack trace is given below:

```html
"ForkJoinPool-1-worker-440" #477 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f0c541c2800 nid=0x2a47 sleeping[0x00007f08e6371000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
 at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 at reactor.util.concurrent.WaitStrategy$Sleeping.waitFor(WaitStrategy.java:319)
 at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.block(MonoProcessor.java:211)
 at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.block(MonoProcessor.java:176)
 at org.springframework.messaging.tcp.reactor.AbstractMonoToListenableFutureAdapter.get(AbstractMonoToListenableFutureAdapter.java:73)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler$SystemStompConnectionHandler.forward(StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java:980)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java:549)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.java:234)
 at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:138)
 at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel.sendInternal(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:94)
 at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:119)
 at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:105)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.sendInternal(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:187)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.doSend(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:162)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.doSend(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:48)
 at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.UserDestinationMessageHandler.handleMessage(UserDestinationMessageHandler.java:227)
 at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:138)
 at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel.sendInternal(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:94)
 at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:119)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.sendInternal(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:187)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.doSend(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:162)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.doSend(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:48)
 at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
 at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:150)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:229)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:218)
 at org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(SimpMessagingTemplate.java:204)
 at com.mypackage.PushMessageManager.lambda$sendMyMessage$2(PushMessageManager.java:77)
 at com.mypackage.PushMessageManager$$Lambda$923/1850582969.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
 at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
 at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
 at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:401)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:734)
 at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
 at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:174)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
 at com.mypackage.PushMessageManager.sendMyMessage(PushMessageManager.java:74)
 at com.mypackage.PushMessageManager.lambda$processPushMessage$0(PushMessageManager.java:61)
 at com.mypackage.PushMessageManager$$Lambda$664/624459498.run(Unknown Source)
 at nl.talsmasoftware.context.functions.RunnableWithContext.run(RunnableWithContext.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at nl.talsmasoftware.context.executors.ContextAwareExecutorService$1.call(ContextAwareExecutorService.java:59)
 at nl.talsmasoftware.context.delegation.RunnableAdapter.run(RunnableAdapter.java:44)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None
```

Steps are mentioned below w.r.t the diagram:

1. Gatling JMS publisher pushes JMS messages at 20000 messages per minute to Active MQ broker. Please note that these messages are not for only one user. it is distributed based on WebSocket user connections.
2. Our application has a JMS listener to receive these messages. We are running say 2 instances of the application so two JMS listeners to process this message.
3. Once the application receives a JMS message it checks the session information from cache to identify the connected users and pushes to another ActiveMQ stomp broker using  simpMessagingTemplate convertAndSendToUser API simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/queue/abc", payload). Please note that the sessionId is stored in a distributed cache when the user first connects to the application. So these are valid session ids.
4. ActiveMQ stomp broker then propagates these messages to individual user stomp queues.
5. The Gatling WebSocket client (each having 2000 user connections) shall receive these messages through WebSocket connections.
6. Client connect and subscribe looks like this

   stompClient.connect({'username': $("#userName").val()}, function (frame) {
       setConnected(true);
       subscription = stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/abc', function (message) {
            showData(JSON.parse(message.body));
        },headers = {'loginusername': $("#userName").val()});
   });

So each user shall receive only the messages intended to them not all the messages. That is the reason we are connecting the users to individual queues while connecting through WebSocket and also use convertAndSendToUser to push the messages to specific sessions. The backend JMS publisher ensures that the messages are published to users in a cyclic fashion.

To answer your question regarding identifying the bottleneck, if we connect say 2000 users everything works fine. But when we add more users, we see that the JMS listener of the application is not able to listen to the 20000 messages per min sent by the backend Gatling JMS load generator. The ActiveMQ JMS queue depth increases due to this.

To make sure that the bottleneck is the convertAndSendToUser API what we did is commented that API call. If we do that we are able to connect ~13k WebSocket connections and the backend JMS listener is able to consume all the 20000 messages per min messages also.

Hope this clarifies some of your questions.
**UPDATE**
Code snippet to show the asynchronous invocation of simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser API is given below. Here RepositoryUtil.executor() is our own wrapper for the executor object.

```
    public CompletableFuture<Void> processPushMessage(String userName, String payload) {
    return ContextAwareCompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        sendABCMessage(payload, userName);
    }, RepositoryUtil.executor());
}

public void sendABCMessage(@Payload String payload, String username) {
    ArrayList<UserProfiles> userProfiles = (ArrayList<UserProfiles>) cacheService.getValue(username);
    if (Objects.nonNull(userProfiles) && userProfiles.size() > 0) {
      userProfiles.parallelStream()
          .filter(userProfiles1 -> ("/user/queue/abc".equalsIgnoreCase(userProfiles1.getSubscribeMapping()) && username.equals(userProfiles1.getUserName())))
          .forEach(userProfiles1 -> {              simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userProfiles1.getSessionId(), "/queue/abc", payload);
          });
    } else {
      LOGGER.info("sendABCMessage userProfiles is null. Payload: {}", payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are able to resolve the issue by moving to /user/topic instead of /user/queue. We are now able to process ~35k per minute messages from backend and 8k web socket user connections.

Answer (score 0):

> The application works fine for 2000 user connections with a load of 20,000 messages per minute. Once we increase the users to 4000 we see that the message generation thread stops.

If you push 20,000 messages to ActiveMQ and each message has 1,000 subscribers, that means 20,000,000 messages (1,000 * 20,000) are published back to WebSocket clients. So try to determine the overall volume of messages flowing through and understand where the bottleneck is (the server forwarding messages to the ActiveMQ, ActiveMQ processing messages, or the server publishing messages to WebSocket clients).

For the 20,000 messages, are they generated from a single thread, or are they sent from a large number of different threads, e.g. as a result of processing messages from WebSocket clients, or  REST HTTP calls? If it is the latter it could be that too many threads are trying to forward messages to the broker concurrently and you may have to apply some kind of rate limits.

At the end of the day you need to understand the overall volume, where the bottleneck is, and where to apply some rate limits.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually, we are using gating WebSocket 
 for the user to connect.

Comment: In the success time, we have connected users of 2000 having different session Ids. Let's say user a1,a2,a3....a1999,a2000 were connected and the 20,000 messages will be for all 2000 users and it will be in a circular fashion.. ie; 20,000/20=10 messages per user or session id. If we increase the connected users to ~4000 then in few minutes all went down. We took the thread dump at the same time and the same pated above.

Comment: @Rossen Stoyanchev I edited the original post by adding a data flow diagram and also I tried to explain the flow.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason for the ActiveMQ (JMS) -> application -> ActiveMQ (STOMP) extra hop through the application? Can whatever is publishing to ActiveMQ (JMS) not also publish to ActiveMQ (STOMP)?

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev The application is a generic component which shall act as a gateway component accepting all the web socket connections, verify the users (tokens), maintain sessions and also act as a generic component which shall process the messages coming from other backend components (through ActiveMQ-JMS) and then publish it to the stomp server. Do you see a bottleneck with such approach?

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev Even if the backend component directly publishes to the AMQ stomp also shall face the same issue since they are also receiving messages from other JMS queues so it is not a possible solution for us. Do you have any performance testing reports regarding the simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser API because we have invested lot of time in this and now this has become a blocker for us to rollout the web push functionality :( . So would appreciate a solution or a workaround.

Comment: What SimpMessagingTempate does is very straight-forward (just look inside). However it is blocking and if you try to push a large number of messages through it on a single thread it will be inefficient because messages are essentially sent one at a time. This is why I asked about the threading model earlier but there is a limit for how detailed a discussion can be on StackOverflow. You're asking questions that require deeper understanding of your architecture. So consider making sure your "gateway" is sending messages in parallel (e.g. by using a thread pool).

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev We are calling the simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser API asynchronously by using an executor with a thread pool size of 400. I have added the code snippet above as an update.

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev Is it possible to get a non-blocking version of the API?